# Dj3 rotation how can i merge?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I add rotate from this code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var w = 300,
      h = 300,
      data = [{
          t: "Now",
          v: 50
        },{
          t: "is",
          v: 25
        },{
          t: "the",
          v: 10
        },{
          t: "winter",
          v: 30
        }];

    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', w)
      .attr('height', h);

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([0, h])
      .domain([60, 0]);

    var label = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.t;
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d,i){
        var xText = i * (w / data.length);
        var yText = h - yScale(d.v);
        return "translate(" + xText + "," + yText + ") rotate(90)";
      })
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "11px");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

To this code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">

        #canvas {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color: red;
        }

        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="canvas" style="border:solid"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    var w = 300,
      h = 300;

    var data = {
      name: "root",
      children: [{
          name: '1',
          size: 70
        },
        {
          name: '2',
          size: 70
        },
        {
          name: '3',
          size: 70
        },
        {
          name: '4',
          size: 70
        },
        {
          name: '5',
          size: 70
        },
        {
          name: '6',
          size: 70
        },
        {
          name: '7',
          size: 70
        },
      ]
    }

        jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
        $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
        return $(this);
        var r = getRandomInt(0, 180);
    };


    var canvas = d3.select("#canvas")
      .append("svg:svg")
      .attr('width', w)
      .attr('height', h);

    var nodes = d3.layout.pack()
      .value(function(d) {
        return d.size;
      })
      .size([w, h])
      .nodes(data);

    nodes.shift();

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
       .range([0, h])
       .domain([60, 0]);

    canvas.selectAll('circles')
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append('svg:circle')
      .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr('r', function(d) {
        return d.r;
      })
      .attr('fill', 'white')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
      .attr('width', 6)
      .attr('height', 6);

    canvas.selectAll("text")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return "Pomidorek";
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "18px")
      .attr("color", "black")
      .attr("transform", function(d,i){
            var xText = i * (w / children.length);
            var yText = h - yScale(d.size);
            return "translate(" + xText + "," + yText + ") rotate(505)";
          })

        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I'm trying but I don't know It's not working.. it's very importan for me. I don't know where I make mistake.. First code rotate text without any troubles, in second code I don't know how can I do this.. I mean add rotate to text,

Answer (score 0):

After a rapid debug I found an error in your code:

```
  .attr("transform", function(d,i){
        var xText = i * (w / children.length); \\error is here: maybe data.children.length
        var yText = h - yScale(d.size);
        return "translate(" + xText + "," + yText + ") rotate(505)";
      })
```

If you run the modified code You can see a rotation but some text goes out of the canvas.